# Have a library reference files within itself but being run from a different library

Tags: c#, selenium, system.io.file

Is it possible to reference a `JSON` file from another library?

I have 3 projects.

- Project A has no libraries
- Project B has a ref, to Project A's Library, and this project also holds a `.json` file.
- Project C has a ref to Project B's Library.

**Problem**

Project B has the code

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns a file located in the BIN/Debug folder path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pFileName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetFile(string pFileName)
{
     return File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, pFileName));
}
```

Since Project C is the project that is being run, Project A is looking in the wrong location.

**Desired Result**

I want to run the project with Project C.

I want the `GetFile` Function to be located in Project A.

And I want the `JSON` file to be stored in Project B.

Very confusing but it makes sense if I dive further down into the code.

Comment: Could you make that path relative?  If you know that the three projects all get output to the same folder, you can simply climb back up the directory tree using `\..` and then back down to the known correct location of your file.  This WILL require some hard-coding of paths however.

Comment: Unfortunatly the paths are not relative. Library B is just that, a .dll

The reason I want this method is because I do not want Project C to have access to change Project Bs file.  If they do, it can break project Bs code.

Comment: If the Json file is a part of the Project A's dll (i.e. It's marked as Embedded Resource in the build actions), then you'll have to make a public accessor for that file from within Project A.  If it's part of the output files (i.e. it's copied to the output folder, alongside the dll) then you can simply use `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the current location of the dll instead of the BaseDirectory call you currently use.  Does this help?  I should say I haven't tested that method...

Comment: Interesting theory, I tried setting the file as Embedded Resource. However I don't think it is working as what I think it is supposed to do. I expect, if i have the file in Project Bs dll. If i have that build output on as embedded resource, i expected to see it pop up in Project A's bin/debug.  Does that sound right?